# How can i put together two sequence with a list generator in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am new in haskell and i got an exercise. In theory i know how i should to do it, but i dont know how can i do it in Haskell. My exercise is create a list generator which generate the following infinite list : `[1,-1,3,-3,5,-5..]`. I would like to do it with two different sequence.

Is there any way to solve this problem something like that:

```
[ something [a,b,a,b..] | a<-[1,3..], b<-[-1,-3..] ]
```

I have already tried to search the solution, but I couldn't find any about list generator.

Comment: It's possible to do something like this, but there's a rather easier way: instead of enumerating the positive and negative numbers separately, enumerate only positive, but yield both the number and its negative.

Comment: I think `[(2*a+1)*b | a <- [0..], b <- [1,-1]]` will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you an hint.

A list generator of the form:

```
[f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

Will perform the *cartesian product* of lists `xs` and `ys` (well, it will apply `f` to each element of the product). Assume `xs = [1,2,3]` and `ys = ['a', 'b']` the above list-comprehension is equivalent to:

```
[f 1 'a', f 1 'b', f 2 'a', f 2 'b', f 3 'a', f 3 'b']
```

so for each element `x` of `xs` the *whole* `ys` is iterated over thus producing all the `f x y0`, `f x y1`, ..., `f x yN` values.

Ask yourself:

- what happens when `ys` is infinite?
- Hence is your approach in anyway feasible with that structure?
- Can you think of an other technique of generating `1` and `-1`, then `3` and `-3` which doesn't require two infinite lists but only one infinite list?

Now try hard to answer these questions yourself, since there's no point in doing exercises if not for actually exercising your mind. I'll provide the answer in spoiler quotes so that if you give up you can have *a possible* solution:

> `[x*y | x <- [1, 3..], y <- [1,-1]]`

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot, sorry for being late with the answer.